# SQL: Extract a word from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following SQL statement that looks for a certain word after the keyword "dispatch level:".

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CadRemarks, CHARINDEX('dispatch level:', CadRemarks) + LEN('dispatch level:'), 6) as 
data
from myTable
```

I would like to upgrade this statement in a way that will return whatever comes between the keyword "dispatch level:" and anything that comes after the word that I'm looking for. So it could be another word, character, or space. For example:

```
Dispatch level: XXXXX YYY
or
Dispatch level: XXXXX

Only return XXXXX
```

EDIT

I'm trying out this SQL, but it selects the word after the word I need, as well.

```
select left(tt.CadRemarks, charindex(' ', tt.CadRemarks+ ' ')) as data
from myTablet cross apply 
 ( values (substring(CadRemarks, charindex('dispatch level:', CadRemarks) + 
16, len(CadRemarks))) 
 ) tt(CadRemarks)
where t.CadRemarks like '%dispatch level:%'
```

the where clause is for me to limit the records, but I will have to move it and make the whole thing as CASE statement. But that's later....

Also tried this, but getting an error (invalid length parameter passed to the left...)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CadRemarks, CHARINDEX('dispatch level: ', CadRemarks) + 
LEN('dispatch level: ') + 1, 
CHARINDEX('', CadRemarks) - (CHARINDEX('dispatch level: ', CadRemarks) + 2 + 
LEN('dispatch level: ')))
FROM myTable
```

Comment: What changes have you made in order to achieve this goal?

Comment: Please add a tag for your DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, etc)

Comment: @nicomp - please see the edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left()` to further find the string :

```
select left(tt.CadRemarks, charindex(' ', tt.CadRemarks+ ' ')) as data
from table t cross apply 
     ( values (substring(CadtRemarks, charindex('dispatch level:', CadRemarks) + 16, len(CadRemarks))) 
     ) tt(CadRemarks);
```